# anonymous function assisment error with timer function

Tags: javascript, html, timer, getelementbyid

I'm trying to set a background-image in a div to change every second or two with the setTimer();  I set it up and it's saying that I have

```
  'Invalid left-hand side in assignment'
```

Not sure what I'm doing that's wrong. Can someone help out please?

```
  <html><body>
  <div class="box">
   <div id="b1"></div>
  </div>
  <input id = 'spin' type="button" value="Spin" onclick='changeIcons()' />
  <script>
  var arr = new Array();
  arr[0] = '1.png';
  arr[1] = '2.png';
  arr[2] = '3.png';
  var first = document.getElementById('b1');

  function changeIcons(){
   for(var spinIcons= 0; spinIcons < 10; spinIcons++){
   arr.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
   var v1 = setTimeout(function(){first.style.background-image= 'url(arr[0])'},   1000);
}
  }
 </script> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

THIS FINALLY ENDED UP WORKING, IT HAS TIMING ISSUES AND i NEED TO MAKE A FRAMED PLACE HOLDER FOR THE BACKGROUNDIMAGES BUT IT'S WORKING:

```
     <div class="first"></div>
     <script>
     for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        $("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(100).fadeIn(400);
     }
     </script>
```

THANKS TO T.J.CROWDER FOR SETTING ME STRAIGHT!!!

Comment: Missing closing brace of your function that's being passed to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: on my actual script it's in there...I just missed it when I was retyping it.

Comment: @Verber: Why the ***heck*** would you "retype" it?! Copy-and-paste, man, to avoid wasting people's time (including your own).

Comment: because there are way more things in the loop on my actual code.  I just was simplifying it for people on here.  So when I copied and pasted I left out a couple things and just retyped it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

The one causing the error you mention is here:

```
//                                        here ------v
var v1 = setTimeout(function(){first.style.background-image= 'url(arr[0])'},   1000);
```

That makes the engine think you're trying to assign to the result of an expression (`background - image`), which is invalid on the left-hand side of an assignment. In JavaScript, property names can't have dashes in them. You can use the camelCase version `backgroundImage` instead.

Separately, you're always setting the background image to the string `'url(arr[0])'`, not putting the value from `arr[0]` in the string. You need to adjust the quotes:

So:

```
var v1 = setTimeout(function(){first.style.backgroundImage= "url(" + arr[0] + ")"},   1000);
```

Some other notes:

- You're setting up the `setTimeout` in a loop, so you're scheduling this to happen 10 times. But those 10 times will all happen one right after another, one second later, and they'll all do exactly the same thing: Set the background image to whatever's in `arr[0]` *at that time*. The fact you're changing the order of the array 10 times previously makes no difference, because the function doesn't receive a copy of the value of `arr[0]` as of when you *schedule* it, it receives an enduring reference to the array, which it uses when it *runs*. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- Sorting the array and using index 0 seems a fairly inefficient way to pick from the array randomly.

Comment: also need to change to `'url(' + arr[0] + ')'`

Comment: @NathanWall: Or probably even `url(' + arr.pop() + ')'` or similar, otherwise it just keeps showing the same image.

Comment: naw that wasn't it.  I have the same error as before.  I don't need to pop as I have this on a loop and am using      
       arr.sort(function(){ return 0.5-Math.random()});

Comment: @Verber: I've updated the answer, now you've changed the question's code.

Comment: I just put in the brace I was missing.  Thanks tho' but as I went back and checked I saw that I had
       backgroundImage 
wrong initially so I fixed that plus the string issue.  I'm seeing that it won't assign to a null value so there's something wrong with my array assignment now.  Thanks for the tips tho!

Comment: @Verber: Just added a couple more, good luck with it.

Comment: It isn't meant to be completely random.  I'm it's just an effect really.  The icons will flicker randomly for a bit then stop (I will add code to avoid duplicates later).  I'm aware it's happening ten times.  In the final code I'll lower the time to say 500 so it's just a quick 2 or 3 second flicker then it stops.  But an any case I still need to solve the issue with my null values.  Thanks for the help @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: @Verber: The point is that the function runs 10 times, but **doesn't** change the background image 10 times. It changes it once, then repeats that *same* change nine further times.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The random sort function is within the for loop so each time through it resorts the array. So loop 1 might be arr[0] loop two might be arr[2] so on and so forth. I just tested it with an alert and it works fine.  It's not perfectly random but it'll do the trick.  I actually am getting rather ridiculous with this as I could just loop through the 3 background images and then stop after 'so many' times.  So the random isn't necessarily needed.  I just want it to 'shuffle' through after my page is loading cause I think it'll look cool.

Comment: @Verber: No, the `sort` happens 10 times before the function setting the background image runs even once. Then the function setting the background image fires 10 times, one second later, **always using the same URL**. See the linked article. To have it use different ones, you'd have to move the array sort *into* the function you're passing into `setTimeout`. [Here's what your code is currently doing](http://jsbin.com/onudam/1) ([Source](http://jsbin.com/onudam/1/edit)). [Here's a minimal mod to make it work](http://jsbin.com/onudam/2) ([Source](http://jsbin.com/onudam/2/edit))

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I see what you're talking about now.  When I was doing alerts it was showing the random sort, but once applied to the background it wasn't changing till the end.  I got it working with some jQuery tho'....the answer is up in the original code.!